# Measure difference in answers on survey depending on item response options

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, psychometrics, population

For my thesis I sent out a questionnaire that has 10 questions. I set defaults: the first seven question had the default set to the desired answer and the last three questions had the default set to the undesired answer.

I want to measure whether people followed the default using SPSS. I am thinking I should use a t-test but this is mainly used to measure a difference between populations, not between questions in one survey. Does anyone have an idea how I can measure if my sample was influenced by the default?

An example of something I would like to test is: two questions are similar but have a different default, did they answer them the same or did they follow the default.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are manipulating item format, or equivalently item response options order. In the psychometric literature, this would call for a model handling item covariates like the Linear Logistic Test Model (LLTM); see, e.g., this review in the *Journal of Statistical Software*, [The Estimation of Item Response Models with the lmer Function from the lme4 Package in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i12).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think the model you propose is too advanced for what I want to do. The respondents answered 10 MC questions and either answered with the default I set or chose one of the other answers. For each question I know the percentage of respondents who chose the default and who didn't. I need a test that can tell me whether there is a significant difference between the percentage that chose the default setting in the first 7 questions (desired answer default) and in the last 3 questions (undesired answer default). I'm looking for a way to analyze that in SPSS.